# Nashorn js eval is much slower than rhino js

Tags: javascript, java, rhino, nashorn

Sample Program

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine jsEngine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
System.out.println(jsEngine.eval("a>10 || b<10 || c=10"));
```

In my program i am using the above code to evaluate 1000's of expressions which uses javascript functions like indexof(),replace,date functions and many more.This kind of expressions used to be evaluated in rhino(when platform java version was java 7) very faster than nashorn.... i should say atleast 15~20 times faster....

Using rhino with Java 8 seems to be a tedious job...can someone suggest the workaround to make it faster...

Comment: And how are you measuring the speed? Do you have some sample code that actually compares the execution times?

Comment: A work around: implement your own parser?  They seem to be simple logical expressions.

Comment: @markspace I just gave example of simple expression but we are using so many functions of javascript such as indexof(),replace,date and many... i will update the question

Comment: @pvg I just made a set of expressions and ran them on java7(rhino) and java8(nashorn) and compared the time difference

Comment: @Attila Szegedi given the answer and it worked... it would be better to explain why people have down voted the question

Answer (score 6):

Rhino has an interpreter, Nashorn compiles every expression to JVM bytecode, and then internally loads and runs the so generated JVM classes. So every eval will, in addition to parsing, incur bytecode generation and JVM class loading cost.

One thing you can do is cast the script engine to a [Compilable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/Compilable.html), and use it to make a `CompiledScript` for repeated invocation.

That won't help if you have many once-evaluated expressions, but it'll help with often-evaluated ones.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked superbly and performance improved very much after this change